# Null Pointer exception in layoutInflate makes no sense. why?

Tags: android, android-layout

The line of code that NPE BOMBS:

```
ViewGroup inflate = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.liker,null);
```

inflate's signature is (int layoutId, View viewRoot)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Comment: This happens many time with me but in my case if I clean the project it is resolved

Comment: nope, still getting this after clean: 07-01 01:11:15.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15223): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post more of you code?

Comment: I don't see how any of the other code is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use View instead of ViewGroup. Please check inflate method returns View